# R Syntax for converting date to SAS date9 format please?

Tags: r

I have a date i.e. 2017-10-23, and want the result to look 23OCT2017 - is as.Date() the correct function? if so, can someone help with with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
format(as.Date('2017-10-23'),'%d-%b-%Y')
```

or using lubridate package

```
paste0(substr(as.Date('2017-10-23'),9,10),
   lubridate::month(as.numeric(substr(as.Date('2017-10-23'),6,7)),label=TRUE,locale='US'),
   substr(as.Date('2017-10-23'),1,4))
```

Comment: Thanks. as.character(oldDate, "%d%b%Y") also worked... and gives same result as your format function - but the month is not in caps i.e. 23Oct2017 - can i get this in caps? (unless converting to caps after making char)

Comment: try paste0(substr(as.Date('2017-10-23'),9,10),
       toupper(lubridate::month(as.numeric(substr(as.Date('2017-10-23'),6,7)),label=TRUE,locale='US')),
       substr(as.Date('2017-10-23'),1,4))

Answer (score 0):

```
toupper(as.character(oldDate, "%d%b%Y"))
```

is what I managed to get to work so far. results in 23OCT2017 for example. if there are better ways, please let me know.